# Blank circles on BW film

Tags: film, development

I just developed a film that came out with transparent circles placed randomically on it and transparent edges.

Example showing the beginning of the film, the shots that always come out totally exposed (sorry the photo it's pretty blurred):
[image: Blank cicles on negative beginning]

It seems that some places of the negative peeled off, so much that something even remained on the reel:

[image: negative peelef off on the]

I've developed using HC-110 and Ilford fixer, the film was an Ilford HP5.

What could've caused this?

Comment: What film were you using?  How old is it?  Have you developed film before?  Has this happened with other rolls you've developed?

Comment: It was a new Ilford HP5 (expires in 2022), I've developed other films before.
Never happened.

Comment: Wild guess would be that the water temperature was too hot and the emulsion melted. Also possible that that particular roll of film was defective...

Comment: not sure if I'm allowed to do this, but I would suggest posting your question on [Photo.net](https://www.photo.net/discuss/forums/film-and-processing.1822/). There are some folk here with plenty of dev expertise, but I think there are even more on Photo.net. If you do that, by all means come back here and share the info.

Comment: 1. Did any of the film develop normally or is it (the edges especially) melty looking all the way through? Do you use any other chemicals in these containers?

Comment: What temperature was used?

Comment: Does your processing procedure include sufficient agitation to ensure there are no bubbles trapped in the spiral?